# Algorithm to place cells in a grid (table)

Tags: java, algorithm

My plan is to place each element in the GridPane on a JavaFX program. But the javafx isn't actually my problem is that I couldn't really go further in the abstraction to create an algorithm with the following characteristics:

This is an example of the algorithm by itself so you don't have to look at unecessary javaFX elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] v1 = {null,"1",null,"3"};
    String[] v2 = {"0","\"1",null,"3"};
    String[] v3= {"4","5","6","","8","9","","11","12","13"};

    int row=0, col=0, index=0;
    String[] v = concat(v1, v3);
    for(String s: v){
        if(s != null && !s.isEmpty()){
            if(index<3){
               if(col<2){
                   col++;
                   index++;
               }
               else{
                   col=0;
                   row++;
                   System.out.println("");
               }
                //System.out.println("index="+index);
               System.out.print("  "+s);
            }
        }
    }
```

The desired output for v1, v3 is:

```
    1  3  6  
    4  5  8 
    11 12 13
```

Desired output for v2, v3 is:

```
    0  1  5  12
    3  4  6  13
    8  9  11
```

As you can see: the objective is to begin at a upperleft square and expand that square when is necessary while not putting any `null or empty` items that might be in the concatenated array.

My code works well for the first 4, but I cannot really think about how should I **expand it in a generic way**. How can I write an generic algorithm for such task?

---

**Edit for clarification:**
using the number of the placed element the placement pattern should look like this:

```
 1 2 5 10
 3 4 6 11
 7 8 9
```

Comment: Where is the 9 from v3 in your example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some Python code I wrote from what I understood about your problem. Hopefully you will be able to translate it.

The main idea is the following: if you finished a square, go fill the rightmost part, from top to bottom, then the bottom part, from left to right.

```
from pprint import pprint

t = range(1,92)
n = len(t)

s = int(n**.5+1)

mat = [[None]*s for _ in range(s)]

i, j = 0, 0
k = 0
st = "right"

while k<n:
    mat[i][j] = t[k]
    k += 1
    if i==j and st=="right":
        i = 0
        j += 1
        st = "down"
    elif st == "right":
        j += 1
    elif i+1==j and st=="down":
        i += 1
        j = 0
        st = "right"
    else:
        i += 1

pprint(mat)
```